# Order is not working with criteria in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have just started working groovy and grails and has some confusion on Order clause with criteria.

Below is my code,

```
def order = "rollNumber"
def orderBy = "asc"


studentListCriteria = Students.createCriteria()

int max = 6
int offset = params?.offset ? Integer.valueOf(params.offset) : 0

def studentList = studentListCriteria.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
        and {
            eq("isActive", Boolean.TRUE )
        }
        order(order,orderBy)
    }
```

While executing it's throw below error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodExceptionMessageNo signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [rollNumber, asc] Possible solutions: wait(), any(), tr(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), trim(), find(), size()
```

Can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong here??

Comment: Please provide more details how you have created studentListCriteria object and other stuff you have written.

Comment: @Pratik, Actually i am using variables for Order clause. where values are coming dynamically. Let me update my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check below Code, You can not use Keywords here.

```
def orderParameter = "rollNumber"//Change name of variable.
def orderByParameter = "asc"


studentListCriteria = Students.createCriteria()

int max = 6
int offset = params?.offset ? Integer.valueOf(params.offset) : 0

def studentList = studentListCriteria.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
        and {
            eq("isActive", Boolean.TRUE )
        }
        order(orderParameter,orderByParameter)
    }
```

Here, you are using `order` as a variable. Please change the name of it and good to go.

Answer (score 1):

It's looks like you have a variable with name `order` in your code before this criteria. Change it's name e.g.,

```
String orderBy = 'someThing'
....
def studentList = studentListCriteria.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
    ....
}
```